# Make a hint to SQLite that a particular column is always sorted

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table in an SQLite database

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `time` REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data` BLOB NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE INDEX `time_index` ON `log`(`time`);
```

The index is created because the most frequent query is going to be

```
SELECT * FROM `log` WHERE `time` BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Since the time is going to be **always** the current time when the new record is added, the index is not really required here. So I would like to "tell" the SQLite engine something like "*The lines are going to be added with the 'time' column always having increasing value (similar to AUTO_INCREMENT), and if something goes wrong I will take all responsibility*".

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Please explain what can go wrong, and what exactly you want to take responsibility for ? And what exactly would SQLite have to do with this information from you?

Comment: When you have an array of sorted values, you can find a particular item in the array by bisecting it rather than making a sequential search. I want to tell SQLite that the rows in the table described above are going to be naturally sorted by the 'time' column. And by 'go wrong' I mean the violation of the "sorted" rule. In this case SQLite might still do bisection even though the lines are not sorted anymore, and I would be completely fine with that.

Comment: One thing: Your have your `time` column with an affinity of `REAL`, but a default value that is a `TEXT` string. Sqlite will happily let you do this, but it looks odd and might mislead people (Including yourself) about the format you intend to use with the column.

Comment: Thank you, @Shawn. Actually, the default value in the real code is different, it computes UNIX time using the `julianday` function. I just wanted simplify my example.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a separate index.  You want to declare the column to be the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `time` REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
  `data` BLOB NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

This creates a single b-tree index for the `log` based on the primary key.  In other databases, this structure would be called a "clustered index".  You have probably already read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) but I'm referencing it anyway.

Comment: That's the solution that I naturally discovered myself, but the problem is that the precision of *REAL* is not enough to handle microsecond resolution, and thus two adjacent records may have the same `time` value which would violate the PRIMARY KEY constraint. Is there a technique to work around this problem? Or is having a separate index my only solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would have an issue, or not depending upon how you consider that you cannot use :-

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `time` REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data` BLOB NOT NULL
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

because :-

> Every WITHOUT ROWID table must have a PRIMARY KEY. An error is raised
>   if a CREATE TABLE statement with the WITHOUT ROWID clause lacks a
>   PRIMARY KEY.
>   [Clustered Indexes and the WITHOUT ROWID Optimization](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)

So you might as well make the **time** column the PRIMARY KEY.

---

> but the problem is that the precision of REAL is not enough to handle
>   microsecond resolution, and thus two adjacent records may have the
>   same time value which would violate the PRIMARY KEY constraint.

Then you could use a composite PRIMARY KEY where the precision required is satisfied by multiple columns (a second column would likely more than suffice) perhaps along the lines of :-

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    time_datepart INTEGER, 
    time_microsecondpart, 
     data BLOB NOt NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (time_datepart,time_microsecondpart)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

The time_microsecondpart column needn't necessarily be microseconds it could be a counter derived from another table similar to how the **sqlite_sequence** table is utilised when AUTOINCREMENT is utilised (less the need for the column that holds the name of the table that a row is attached to).